# CSS flexbox make main content scrollable

Tags: css

I have a page layout of an header, a sidebar, and a main content. I'm using flexbox to create the layout but I want **only the main content** to be scrollable.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  height: 30px;
  background: #000;
}

div {
  display: flex;
}

aside {
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  height: calc(100vh - 30px);
  overflow: auto;
}

.main {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header>
    header
  </header>
  
  <div>
    
    <aside>Sidebar</aside>
    <section class="main">
      
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi ducimus odit optio dicta placeat dolore beatae dolorum quos corporis vitae aliquid enim cumque aperiam molestiae eligendi a omnis, magni sint!
      Voluptatum facere minima nulla atque quis, consequuntur minus excepturi! Id nesciunt ullam inventore commodi adipisci iure recusandae temporibus placeat perspiciatis consequuntur voluptatum ex, sint non cumque eos libero quis. Qui.
      Ea ut alias, quasi recusandae unde maiores reiciendis corrupti at natus eligendi et, quas adipisci consectetur iusto eum perspiciatis rem nesciunt illum magni incidunt cum aperiam quos ipsum! Officia, autem.
      Laudantium dolorem aliquid, distinctio possimus molestiae voluptates quis. Repudiandae eius id perferendis minima fugit quam, placeat saepe quae? Libero delectus corporis soluta debitis explicabo, rerum odit aliquam. Voluptatibus, delectus? Quia!
      Illo, quo excepturi eveniet sint veritatis et sunt voluptas? Autem recusandae dolores totam exercitationem distinctio minima, eaque soluta saepe sint blanditiis sequi deleniti quibusdam facere reprehenderit, debitis fuga quas suscipit!
      Temporibus, quam amet, ab modi assumenda minus esse, impedit vitae accusamus et ipsa! Amet quis cum labore minima corporis! Harum incidunt quae voluptas fugiat quod aut earum unde, reiciendis aspernatur.
      Magni sequi doloremque, facilis iste quasi sed repudiandae repellat cum voluptas repellendus beatae ullam asperiores voluptatem cupiditate voluptatibus architecto tempora deleniti aperiam mollitia sint praesentium in! Mollitia nemo modi perferendis!
      Architecto quos vel voluptate maxime iste quis impedit nam nostrum earum suscipit. A quidem repellendus exercitationem voluptatum magni facilis repellat impedit dignissimos adipisci quaerat non, doloremque laudantium neque, ipsum minima.
      Explicabo nobis fugit quaerat, deleniti fuga natus, architecto minima ipsam vitae dicta, beatae voluptatem. Numquam accusamus error ducimus ut culpa maiores eveniet necessitatibus. Quo autem recusandae praesentium officia dolorem pariatur?
      Deleniti voluptatem similique, rem qui exercitationem, aut fuga consequuntur pariatur quibusdam cupiditate amet vero et id hic recusandae nesciunt fugit. Doloribus est ducimus necessitatibus maiores expedita pariatur obcaecati omnis ut!
      Amet itaque ut sed? Hic facilis voluptatum nulla necessitatibus nihil optio distinctio rerum omnis temporibus vero similique repellendus eveniet in velit illo obcaecati repellat aliquid possimus aspernatur, quo libero molestias.
      Eaque sequi dolorum modi error cumque repellat excepturi sint, accusantium minima aspernatur quam quas expedita quae recusandae voluptatum nulla dolor ratione sit autem et perferendis. Laudantium sint est unde consectetur.
      Nostrum saepe inventore nam commodi provident, repellat praesentium molestias doloribus optio porro quibusdam est voluptates labore quod at soluta mollitia, placeat, aut eos excepturi maiores ab. Fugiat nemo facilis illo?
      Harum corporis inventore esse, tempora ipsum, sit necessitatibus eaque in mollitia voluptates dolorum doloremque natus ab. Quasi consequatur veniam voluptate obcaecati dolorem fuga omnis quibusdam numquam dignissimos et! A, rem.
      Dolorem nihil placeat non, est odio temporibus eum voluptate mollitia, reprehenderit rem vero officiis beatae consequuntur quos cupiditate nobis aliquid iure quidem ducimus impedit ex illo necessitatibus. Qui, magnam ea!
      Earum quae unde dolorem molestias at itaque magni doloremque consequuntur! Voluptatem odio dolorum, ea optio nihil deserunt eius tempore nisi. Doloremque reprehenderit non, harum eius commodi necessitatibus voluptas. Reiciendis, ratione?
      Omnis fugit dignissimos esse magni rem doloremque quisquam deleniti iusto ut impedit laudantium error ab earum minima qui culpa ipsa rerum, quam, perferendis veritatis! Ut voluptatum tempore asperiores expedita voluptate.
      Harum molestiae natus sapiente libero, voluptatum vero unde aut consequuntur tempore voluptatibus minima iure earum accusantium quaerat nesciunt dolorum fugiat repellat numquam et neque aliquam. Blanditiis modi illo facere autem?
      Aliquid ut nam laboriosam officia qui tempora pariatur delectus, consectetur sapiente ipsum hic ab alias? Numquam aut doloribus veritatis amet quos veniam eos. Quidem laborum qui exercitationem dignissimos eaque officiis?
      Fuga magni provident, excepturi, unde saepe architecto ad eum maxime amet nesciunt laudantium? Ea obcaecati reprehenderit cum sit suscipit minus dolore porro reiciendis dicta? Iusto officiis nam modi dolorem beatae.
    </section>
  </div>
</main>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Not footer. Sidebar

Comment: Do you want to the text part to be scrollable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it to your CSS

```
.main {
  flex: 1;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 30px);
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add [overflow Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

here is an example

```css
body{
  overflow :hidden;
}
.main {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  height : 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: #777;
}

div {
  display: flex;
}

aside {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  height: calc(100vh - 30px);
  overflow: auto;
}

.main {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header>
    header
  </header>
  
  <div>
    
    <aside>Sidebar</aside>
    <section class="main">
      
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi ducimus odit optio dicta placeat dolore beatae dolorum quos corporis vitae aliquid enim cumque aperiam molestiae eligendi a omnis, magni sint!
      Voluptatum facere minima nulla atque quis, consequuntur minus excepturi! Id nesciunt ullam inventore commodi adipisci iure recusandae temporibus placeat perspiciatis consequuntur voluptatum ex, sint non cumque eos libero quis. Qui.
      Ea ut alias, quasi recusandae unde maiores reiciendis corrupti at natus eligendi et, quas adipisci consectetur iusto eum perspiciatis rem nesciunt illum magni incidunt cum aperiam quos ipsum! Officia, autem.
      Laudantium dolorem aliquid, distinctio possimus molestiae voluptates quis. Repudiandae eius id perferendis minima fugit quam, placeat saepe quae? Libero delectus corporis soluta debitis explicabo, rerum odit aliquam. Voluptatibus, delectus? Quia!
      Illo, quo excepturi eveniet sint veritatis et sunt voluptas? Autem recusandae dolores totam exercitationem distinctio minima, eaque soluta saepe sint blanditiis sequi deleniti quibusdam facere reprehenderit, debitis fuga quas suscipit!
      Temporibus, quam amet, ab modi assumenda minus esse, impedit vitae accusamus et ipsa! Amet quis cum labore minima corporis! Harum incidunt quae voluptas fugiat quod aut earum unde, reiciendis aspernatur.
      Magni sequi doloremque, facilis iste quasi sed repudiandae repellat cum voluptas repellendus beatae ullam asperiores voluptatem cupiditate voluptatibus architecto tempora deleniti aperiam mollitia sint praesentium in! Mollitia nemo modi perferendis!
      Architecto quos vel voluptate maxime iste quis impedit nam nostrum earum suscipit. A quidem repellendus exercitationem voluptatum magni facilis repellat impedit dignissimos adipisci quaerat non, doloremque laudantium neque, ipsum minima.
      Explicabo nobis fugit quaerat, deleniti fuga natus, architecto minima ipsam vitae dicta, beatae voluptatem. Numquam accusamus error ducimus ut culpa maiores eveniet necessitatibus. Quo autem recusandae praesentium officia dolorem pariatur?
      Deleniti voluptatem similique, rem qui exercitationem, aut fuga consequuntur pariatur quibusdam cupiditate amet vero et id hic recusandae nesciunt fugit. Doloribus est ducimus necessitatibus maiores expedita pariatur obcaecati omnis ut!
      Amet itaque ut sed? Hic facilis voluptatum nulla necessitatibus nihil optio distinctio rerum omnis temporibus vero similique repellendus eveniet in velit illo obcaecati repellat aliquid possimus aspernatur, quo libero molestias.
      Eaque sequi dolorum modi error cumque repellat excepturi sint, accusantium minima aspernatur quam quas expedita quae recusandae voluptatum nulla dolor ratione sit autem et perferendis. Laudantium sint est unde consectetur.
      Nostrum saepe inventore nam commodi provident, repellat praesentium molestias doloribus optio porro quibusdam est voluptates labore quod at soluta mollitia, placeat, aut eos excepturi maiores ab. Fugiat nemo facilis illo?
      Harum corporis inventore esse, tempora ipsum, sit necessitatibus eaque in mollitia voluptates dolorum doloremque natus ab. Quasi consequatur veniam voluptate obcaecati dolorem fuga omnis quibusdam numquam dignissimos et! A, rem.
      Dolorem nihil placeat non, est odio temporibus eum voluptate mollitia, reprehenderit rem vero officiis beatae consequuntur quos cupiditate nobis aliquid iure quidem ducimus impedit ex illo necessitatibus. Qui, magnam ea!
      Earum quae unde dolorem molestias at itaque magni doloremque consequuntur! Voluptatem odio dolorum, ea optio nihil deserunt eius tempore nisi. Doloremque reprehenderit non, harum eius commodi necessitatibus voluptas. Reiciendis, ratione?
      Omnis fugit dignissimos esse magni rem doloremque quisquam deleniti iusto ut impedit laudantium error ab earum minima qui culpa ipsa rerum, quam, perferendis veritatis! Ut voluptatum tempore asperiores expedita voluptate.
      Harum molestiae natus sapiente libero, voluptatum vero unde aut consequuntur tempore voluptatibus minima iure earum accusantium quaerat nesciunt dolorum fugiat repellat numquam et neque aliquam. Blanditiis modi illo facere autem?
      Aliquid ut nam laboriosam officia qui tempora pariatur delectus, consectetur sapiente ipsum hic ab alias? Numquam aut doloribus veritatis amet quos veniam eos. Quidem laborum qui exercitationem dignissimos eaque officiis?
      Fuga magni provident, excepturi, unde saepe architecto ad eum maxime amet nesciunt laudantium? Ea obcaecati reprehenderit cum sit suscipit minus dolore porro reiciendis dicta? Iusto officiis nam modi dolorem beatae.
    </section>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your text in `p` tag like below.

```
<main>
  <header>
    header
  </header>
  
  <div>
    
    <aside>Sidebar</aside>
    <section class="main">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi ducimus odit optio dicta placeat dolore beatae dolorum quos corporis vitae aliquid enim cumque aperiam molestiae eligendi a omnis, magni sint!
      Voluptatum facere minima nulla atque quis, consequuntur minus excepturi! Id nesciunt ullam inventore commodi adipisci iure recusandae temporibus placeat perspiciatis consequuntur voluptatum ex, sint non cumque eos libero quis. Qui.
      Ea ut alias, quasi recusandae unde maiores reiciendis corrupti at natus eligendi et, quas adipisci consectetur iusto eum perspiciatis rem nesciunt illum magni incidunt cum aperiam quos ipsum! Officia, autem.
      Laudantium dolorem aliquid, distinctio possimus molestiae voluptates quis. Repudiandae eius id perferendis minima fugit quam, placeat saepe quae? Libero delectus corporis soluta debitis explicabo, rerum odit aliquam. Voluptatibus, delectus? Quia!
      Illo, quo excepturi eveniet sint veritatis et sunt voluptas? Autem recusandae dolores totam exercitationem distinctio minima, eaque soluta saepe sint blanditiis sequi deleniti quibusdam facere reprehenderit, debitis fuga quas suscipit!
      Temporibus, quam amet, ab modi assumenda minus esse, impedit vitae accusamus et ipsa! Amet quis cum labore minima corporis! Harum incidunt quae voluptas fugiat quod aut earum unde, reiciendis aspernatur.
      Magni sequi doloremque, facilis iste quasi sed repudiandae repellat cum voluptas repellendus beatae ullam asperiores voluptatem cupiditate voluptatibus architecto tempora deleniti aperiam mollitia sint praesentium in! Mollitia nemo modi perferendis!
      Architecto quos vel voluptate maxime iste quis impedit nam nostrum earum suscipit. A quidem repellendus exercitationem voluptatum magni facilis repellat impedit dignissimos adipisci quaerat non, doloremque laudantium neque, ipsum minima.
      Explicabo nobis fugit quaerat, deleniti fuga natus, architecto minima ipsam vitae dicta, beatae voluptatem. Numquam accusamus error ducimus ut culpa maiores eveniet necessitatibus. Quo autem recusandae praesentium officia dolorem pariatur?
      Deleniti voluptatem similique, rem qui exercitationem, aut fuga consequuntur pariatur quibusdam cupiditate amet vero et id hic recusandae nesciunt fugit. Doloribus est ducimus necessitatibus maiores expedita pariatur obcaecati omnis ut!
      Amet itaque ut sed? Hic facilis voluptatum nulla necessitatibus nihil optio distinctio rerum omnis temporibus vero similique repellendus eveniet in velit illo obcaecati repellat aliquid possimus aspernatur, quo libero molestias.
      Eaque sequi dolorum modi error cumque repellat excepturi sint, accusantium minima aspernatur quam quas expedita quae recusandae voluptatum nulla dolor ratione sit autem et perferendis. Laudantium sint est unde consectetur.
      Nostrum saepe inventore nam commodi provident, repellat praesentium molestias doloribus optio porro quibusdam est voluptates labore quod at soluta mollitia, placeat, aut eos excepturi maiores ab. Fugiat nemo facilis illo?
      Harum corporis inventore esse, tempora ipsum, sit necessitatibus eaque in mollitia voluptates dolorum doloremque natus ab. Quasi consequatur veniam voluptate obcaecati dolorem fuga omnis quibusdam numquam dignissimos et! A, rem.
      Dolorem nihil placeat non, est odio temporibus eum voluptate mollitia, reprehenderit rem vero officiis beatae consequuntur quos cupiditate nobis aliquid iure quidem ducimus impedit ex illo necessitatibus. Qui, magnam ea!
      Earum quae unde dolorem molestias at itaque magni doloremque consequuntur! Voluptatem odio dolorum, ea optio nihil deserunt eius tempore nisi. Doloremque reprehenderit non, harum eius commodi necessitatibus voluptas. Reiciendis, ratione?
      Omnis fugit dignissimos esse magni rem doloremque quisquam deleniti iusto ut impedit laudantium error ab earum minima qui culpa ipsa rerum, quam, perferendis veritatis! Ut voluptatum tempore asperiores expedita voluptate.
      Harum molestiae natus sapiente libero, voluptatum vero unde aut consequuntur tempore voluptatibus minima iure earum accusantium quaerat nesciunt dolorum fugiat repellat numquam et neque aliquam. Blanditiis modi illo facere autem?
      Aliquid ut nam laboriosam officia qui tempora pariatur delectus, consectetur sapiente ipsum hic ab alias? Numquam aut doloribus veritatis amet quos veniam eos. Quidem laborum qui exercitationem dignissimos eaque officiis?
      Fuga magni provident, excepturi, unde saepe architecto ad eum maxime amet nesciunt laudantium? Ea obcaecati reprehenderit cum sit suscipit minus dolore porro reiciendis dicta? Iusto officiis nam modi dolorem beatae.
      </p>
      
    </section>
  </div>
</main>
```

Give p tag fixed height set its overflow property to scroll like below.

```
p {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this :

```
.main {
    height: calc(100vh - 30px);
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The position sticky will keep it always to the left.

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  height: 30px;
  background: #000;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

aside {
  width: 20%;
  background: red;
  height: calc(100vh - 30px);
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  top:0;
}

.main {
  flex:1;
    width: 70%;
}
```